# Python difflib.get_close_matches search on dictionary value - how do I return the key?

Tags: python, dictionary, difflib

I have an example Python dictionary as follows:

```
mydict={1:'Halibut',2:'Halibat',3:'Halibert',4:'Halibut'}
```

Note that there are non-unique values in there (items 1 and 4). I can do a search on the values using difflib.get_close_matches as follows:

```
difflib.get_close_matches('Halibott',mydict.values(),n=3,cutoff=0.8)
['Halibut', 'Halibut', 'Halibat']
```

Is it possible to also return the keys (1,4,2) using difflib or will I have to resort to a reverse lookup search after getting the results?

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, kindly mark it as the right answer, or if any other clarifications are needed, you can comment on the existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think you can get the keys using the  `difflib.get_close_matches` function. But you can write your own function to do the same -

```
def sequence_matcher(input_dict, n, cutoff):
    input_list = input_dict.items()
    matches = list() 
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        if len(matches) > n:
            break
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'Halibott', value).ratio() >= cutoff:
            matches.append([key, value])       
    return matches

mydict={1:'Halibut',2:'Halibat',3:'Halibert',4:'Halibut'}
sequence_matcher(mydict, 3, 0.8) # Output - [[1, 'Halibut'], [2, 'Halibat'], [4, 'Halibut']]
```